# Sum of characters in textbox

Tags: c#, .net

I'm tasked with building a program that performs math based on letters.  Every letter has one value.  For example, `A=1`, `B=2` and `C=3`.  The user will enter a series of letters in a text box.  If the user enters `ABC`, the result would be `6`.

How do I perform this math?

Here is a picture of the user interface I have built:
[image]

Comment: @BoltClock : mine don't work! ;)

Comment: @Mitch - This ones got me speechless!

Comment: Should I answer him? 1 more vote down!

Comment: @W.N. : if you have the answer, what's the question?

Comment: @Mitch Wheat: This look like a homework. He is meaning that calculate the sum of "character", which, every character represent a number. For example A = 1, B = 2, so if the textbox is ABB => result: 1 + 2 + 2 = 5.

Comment: It seems the question itself is written in some programming language .. use of ! [] and capital letters

Comment: @Ankur: That's actually the markdown syntax showing through. He tried to make the entire thing a link to an image. Fixed it now. Still not sure what the question is.

Comment: Hah, looks like I answered closed question :(.

Comment: @BoltClock : actually, I think the drugs are working now. Either that or those labels are all over the place.

Comment: @Cody Gray He meant "sum of characters" by "some of characters".

Comment: @Episodex: Oh, I didn't know someone here read this language. Please feel free to edit the question yourself. I just modified the case of the letters, not the content. (Of course, it doesn't make much sense to sum the ASCII values of letters...)

Comment: @Cody Gray Being not-native English speaker helps in such situations ;). Anyway, I don't have enough rep to edit this question...

Comment: @Episodex: Sure you do. Well, I mean, you sort of do. You can still click on the edit link and propose an edit. It just has to be approved by two other users before it takes effect. But if it's a good edit, it'll get approved, and you'll get +2 rep for your effort.

Comment: So... anyone wanna vote to reopen this?

Comment: @Cody Gray Can't find it anywhere (there are only `link` and `flag`). Maybe it's because the question is closed.

Comment: @Episodex: Oh yeah. That's right. I forgot that suggested edits don't work on closed questions. There's an open bug report about it now, actually. Sorry for the confusion! Anyway, in general you can do that. :-)

Comment: "Gentlemen, we can rebuild him.  We have the technology."  Rewrote question to actually be answerable.

Answer (score 2):

```
var text = "Abc";
text = text.ToUpper();
var sum = 0;
foreach (char c in text)
{
    sum += c - 64;
}
```

`sum` has your value.